# Add link rel next/prev on Prestashop in header.tpl

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add links for next/prev in a prestashop site.

Unfortunately, everything i've tried doesnt work... except canonical rel.

This is what i've tried:

```
{if $start!=$stop} 
{if $p != 1} 
{assign var='p_previous' value=$p-1} 
<link rel="prev" href="/{$request_uri|substr:1|regex_replace:'/\/(.*)/':''|regex_replace:'/\?(.*)/':''}/{$link->goPage($requestPage, $p_previous)}" /> 
{else} 
{/if} 
{if $pages_nb > 1 AND $p != $pages_nb} 
{assign var='p_next' value=$p+1} 
<link rel="next" href="/{$request_uri|substr:1|regex_replace:'/\/(.*)/':''|regex_replace:'/\?(.*)/':''}/{$link->goPage($requestPage, $p_next)}" /> 
{else} 
{/if} 
{/if}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to display <link rel="next/prev"> in category on prestashop.

Answer (score -1):

We recommend you to try out demo of the [Prev Next product](http://www.knowband.com/prestashop-prev-next-buttons?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=prestashop&utm_term=prev-next&utm_campaign=participation) module. This module shows previous next buttons on product pages and helps customers to navigate through products of the same category.

You can also tweak this module code to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Hei, thanks for your answer but its not about the nexdt and prev buttons, its about head links with rel next/prev